# API JSON Response Select Lowest Price

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm making an AJAX call to an API and getting the following json (below) response. I'm wanting to get the lowest 'MinPrice' from 'Quotes', but can't seem to figure out the best approach.

I can loop through the quotes and push each minprice into an array, and then sort that array to get the lowest value, but I also want that specific quotes extra information i.e it's 'outboundleg'.

```
{
    "Quotes": [{
        "QuoteId": 1,
        "MinPrice": 70.0,
        "Direct": true,
        "OutboundLeg": {
            "CarrierIds": [1047],
            "OriginId": 84892,
            "DestinationId": 65698,
            "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
        },
        "QuoteDateTime": "2017-02-01T01:05:00"
    }, {
        "QuoteId": 2,
        "MinPrice": 85.0,
        "Direct": true,
        "InboundLeg": {
            "CarrierIds": [1047],
            "OriginId": 65698,
            "DestinationId": 84892,
            "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
        },
        "QuoteDateTime": "2017-02-01T04:23:00"
    }, {
        "QuoteId": 3,
        "MinPrice": 86.0,
        "Direct": true,
        "InboundLeg": {
            "CarrierIds": [1047],
            "OriginId": 65698,
            "DestinationId": 84892,
            "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
        },
        "QuoteDateTime": "2017-02-01T01:57:00"
    }, {
        "QuoteId": 4,
        "MinPrice": 164.0,
        "Direct": true,
        "OutboundLeg": {
            "CarrierIds": [1047],
            "OriginId": 84892,
            "DestinationId": 65698,
            "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
        },
        "InboundLeg": {
            "CarrierIds": [1047],
            "OriginId": 65698,
            "DestinationId": 84892,
            "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
        },
        "QuoteDateTime": "2017-01-30T21:03:00"
    }],
    "Places": [{
        "PlaceId": 65698,
        "IataCode": "LHR",
        "Name": "London Heathrow",
        "Type": "Station",
        "SkyscannerCode": "LHR",
        "CityName": "London",
        "CityId": "LOND",
        "CountryName": "United Kingdom"
    }, {
        "PlaceId": 84892,
        "IataCode": "TXL",
        "Name": "Berlin Tegel",
        "Type": "Station",
        "SkyscannerCode": "TXL",
        "CityName": "Berlin",
        "CityId": "BERL",
        "CountryName": "Germany"
    }],
    "Carriers": [{
        "CarrierId": 838,
        "Name": "Air France"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 881,
        "Name": "British Airways"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1047,
        "Name": "eurowings"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1218,
        "Name": "Iberia"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1324,
        "Name": "KLM"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1368,
        "Name": "Lufthansa"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1384,
        "Name": "Swiss"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1707,
        "Name": "SAS"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1710,
        "Name": "Brussels Airlines"
    }],
    "Currencies": [{
        "Code": "GBP",
        "Symbol": "£",
        "ThousandsSeparator": ",",
        "DecimalSeparator": ".",
        "SymbolOnLeft": true,
        "SpaceBetweenAmountAndSymbol": false,
        "RoundingCoefficient": 0,
        "DecimalDigits": 2
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Quotes` is an array, [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) it on the basis of `MinPrice` propert and then you can extract information on the basis of `index`.

```
var sorted = data.Quotes.sort((a, b) => {return a.MinPrice - b.MinPrice})
console.log(sorted[0])
```

```js
var data = {
  "Quotes": [{
    "QuoteId": 1,
    "MinPrice": 70.0,
    "Direct": true,
    "OutboundLeg": {
      "CarrierIds": [1047],
      "OriginId": 84892,
      "DestinationId": 65698,
      "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
    },
    "QuoteDateTime": "2017-02-01T01:05:00"
  }, {
    "QuoteId": 2,
    "MinPrice": 85.0,
    "Direct": true,
    "InboundLeg": {
      "CarrierIds": [1047],
      "OriginId": 65698,
      "DestinationId": 84892,
      "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
    },
    "QuoteDateTime": "2017-02-01T04:23:00"
  }, {
    "QuoteId": 3,
    "MinPrice": 86.0,
    "Direct": true,
    "InboundLeg": {
      "CarrierIds": [1047],
      "OriginId": 65698,
      "DestinationId": 84892,
      "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
    },
    "QuoteDateTime": "2017-02-01T01:57:00"
  }, {
    "QuoteId": 4,
    "MinPrice": 164.0,
    "Direct": true,
    "OutboundLeg": {
      "CarrierIds": [1047],
      "OriginId": 84892,
      "DestinationId": 65698,
      "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
    },
    "InboundLeg": {
      "CarrierIds": [1047],
      "OriginId": 65698,
      "DestinationId": 84892,
      "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
    },
    "QuoteDateTime": "2017-01-30T21:03:00"
  }],
  "Places": [{
    "PlaceId": 65698,
    "IataCode": "LHR",
    "Name": "London Heathrow",
    "Type": "Station",
    "SkyscannerCode": "LHR",
    "CityName": "London",
    "CityId": "LOND",
    "CountryName": "United Kingdom"
  }, {
    "PlaceId": 84892,
    "IataCode": "TXL",
    "Name": "Berlin Tegel",
    "Type": "Station",
    "SkyscannerCode": "TXL",
    "CityName": "Berlin",
    "CityId": "BERL",
    "CountryName": "Germany"
  }],
  "Carriers": [{
    "CarrierId": 838,
    "Name": "Air France"
  }, {
    "CarrierId": 881,
    "Name": "British Airways"
  }, {
    "CarrierId": 1047,
    "Name": "eurowings"
  }, {
    "CarrierId": 1218,
    "Name": "Iberia"
  }, {
    "CarrierId": 1324,
    "Name": "KLM"
  }, {
    "CarrierId": 1368,
    "Name": "Lufthansa"
  }, {
    "CarrierId": 1384,
    "Name": "Swiss"
  }, {
    "CarrierId": 1707,
    "Name": "SAS"
  }, {
    "CarrierId": 1710,
    "Name": "Brussels Airlines"
  }],
  "Currencies": [{
    "Code": "GBP",
    "Symbol": "£",
    "ThousandsSeparator": ",",
    "DecimalSeparator": ".",
    "SymbolOnLeft": true,
    "SpaceBetweenAmountAndSymbol": false,
    "RoundingCoefficient": 0,
    "DecimalDigits": 2
  }]
};

var sorted = data.Quotes.sort((a, b) => {return a.MinPrice - b.MinPrice})
console.log(sorted[0])
```

Comment: This is actually what I was looking for, thank you Satpa

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function which accept as argument a `callback` function.

```
var minPrices=obj.Quotes.sort(function(item1,item2){
     return item1.MinPrice-item2.MinPrice;
});
```

Once we sorted the `quotes`, `minPrices[0]` returns the object with the lowers `MinPrice`.

```js
var obj={
    "Quotes": [{
        "QuoteId": 1,
        "MinPrice": 70.0,
        "Direct": true,
        "OutboundLeg": {
            "CarrierIds": [1047],
            "OriginId": 84892,
            "DestinationId": 65698,
            "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
        },
        "QuoteDateTime": "2017-02-01T01:05:00"
    }, {
        "QuoteId": 2,
        "MinPrice": 85.0,
        "Direct": true,
        "InboundLeg": {
            "CarrierIds": [1047],
            "OriginId": 65698,
            "DestinationId": 84892,
            "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
        },
        "QuoteDateTime": "2017-02-01T04:23:00"
    }, {
        "QuoteId": 3,
        "MinPrice": 86.0,
        "Direct": true,
        "InboundLeg": {
            "CarrierIds": [1047],
            "OriginId": 65698,
            "DestinationId": 84892,
            "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
        },
        "QuoteDateTime": "2017-02-01T01:57:00"
    }, {
        "QuoteId": 4,
        "MinPrice": 164.0,
        "Direct": true,
        "OutboundLeg": {
            "CarrierIds": [1047],
            "OriginId": 84892,
            "DestinationId": 65698,
            "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
        },
        "InboundLeg": {
            "CarrierIds": [1047],
            "OriginId": 65698,
            "DestinationId": 84892,
            "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
        },
        "QuoteDateTime": "2017-01-30T21:03:00"
    }],
    "Places": [{
        "PlaceId": 65698,
        "IataCode": "LHR",
        "Name": "London Heathrow",
        "Type": "Station",
        "SkyscannerCode": "LHR",
        "CityName": "London",
        "CityId": "LOND",
        "CountryName": "United Kingdom"
    }, {
        "PlaceId": 84892,
        "IataCode": "TXL",
        "Name": "Berlin Tegel",
        "Type": "Station",
        "SkyscannerCode": "TXL",
        "CityName": "Berlin",
        "CityId": "BERL",
        "CountryName": "Germany"
    }],
    "Carriers": [{
        "CarrierId": 838,
        "Name": "Air France"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 881,
        "Name": "British Airways"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1047,
        "Name": "eurowings"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1218,
        "Name": "Iberia"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1324,
        "Name": "KLM"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1368,
        "Name": "Lufthansa"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1384,
        "Name": "Swiss"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1707,
        "Name": "SAS"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1710,
        "Name": "Brussels Airlines"
    }],
    "Currencies": [{
        "Code": "GBP",
        "Symbol": "£",
        "ThousandsSeparator": ",",
        "DecimalSeparator": ".",
        "SymbolOnLeft": true,
        "SpaceBetweenAmountAndSymbol": false,
        "RoundingCoefficient": 0,
        "DecimalDigits": 2
    }]
}
var minPrices=obj.Quotes.sort(function(item1,item2){
    return item1.MinPrice-item2.MinPrice;
});
console.log(minPrices[0]);
```

If you want to obtain only the `MinPrice`, you should use  `map` function in order to obtain all `MinPrice` from `Quotes`.

Then, you have to `sort` array using `sort()` function which accept as argument a `callback` function.

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){
   return a-b;
});
```

The last step is to get the first `element` of sorted array, which represents the `lowest` **MinPrice**.

```js
var obj={
    "Quotes": [{
        "QuoteId": 1,
        "MinPrice": 70.0,
        "Direct": true,
        "OutboundLeg": {
            "CarrierIds": [1047],
            "OriginId": 84892,
            "DestinationId": 65698,
            "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
        },
        "QuoteDateTime": "2017-02-01T01:05:00"
    }, {
        "QuoteId": 2,
        "MinPrice": 85.0,
        "Direct": true,
        "InboundLeg": {
            "CarrierIds": [1047],
            "OriginId": 65698,
            "DestinationId": 84892,
            "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
        },
        "QuoteDateTime": "2017-02-01T04:23:00"
    }, {
        "QuoteId": 3,
        "MinPrice": 86.0,
        "Direct": true,
        "InboundLeg": {
            "CarrierIds": [1047],
            "OriginId": 65698,
            "DestinationId": 84892,
            "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
        },
        "QuoteDateTime": "2017-02-01T01:57:00"
    }, {
        "QuoteId": 4,
        "MinPrice": 164.0,
        "Direct": true,
        "OutboundLeg": {
            "CarrierIds": [1047],
            "OriginId": 84892,
            "DestinationId": 65698,
            "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
        },
        "InboundLeg": {
            "CarrierIds": [1047],
            "OriginId": 65698,
            "DestinationId": 84892,
            "DepartureDate": "2017-02-13T00:00:00"
        },
        "QuoteDateTime": "2017-01-30T21:03:00"
    }],
    "Places": [{
        "PlaceId": 65698,
        "IataCode": "LHR",
        "Name": "London Heathrow",
        "Type": "Station",
        "SkyscannerCode": "LHR",
        "CityName": "London",
        "CityId": "LOND",
        "CountryName": "United Kingdom"
    }, {
        "PlaceId": 84892,
        "IataCode": "TXL",
        "Name": "Berlin Tegel",
        "Type": "Station",
        "SkyscannerCode": "TXL",
        "CityName": "Berlin",
        "CityId": "BERL",
        "CountryName": "Germany"
    }],
    "Carriers": [{
        "CarrierId": 838,
        "Name": "Air France"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 881,
        "Name": "British Airways"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1047,
        "Name": "eurowings"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1218,
        "Name": "Iberia"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1324,
        "Name": "KLM"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1368,
        "Name": "Lufthansa"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1384,
        "Name": "Swiss"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1707,
        "Name": "SAS"
    }, {
        "CarrierId": 1710,
        "Name": "Brussels Airlines"
    }],
    "Currencies": [{
        "Code": "GBP",
        "Symbol": "£",
        "ThousandsSeparator": ",",
        "DecimalSeparator": ".",
        "SymbolOnLeft": true,
        "SpaceBetweenAmountAndSymbol": false,
        "RoundingCoefficient": 0,
        "DecimalDigits": 2
    }]
}
var minPrices=obj.Quotes.map(function(item){
    return item.MinPrice;
}).sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
console.log(minPrices[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort function to sort you array of objects.

```
var quotes = a["Quotes"];

quotes.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.MinPrice - b.MinPrice;
});


console.log(JSON.stringify(quotes));
```